# List manipulation in python with 3 lists in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of lists - essentially

```
[ [[val1, val2...], [val3, val4...]...], [[val5, val6...], [val7, val8...]...], ...]
```

On python, pretty printed, the output looks like:

```
[[['a',
   'b',
   'c',
   'test1',
   'd',
   'e',
   'f',
   'g'],
  ['h',
   'i',
   'j',
   'k',
   'l',
   'm']],
 [['n',
   'o',
   'p',
   'test2',
   'q',
   'r',
   's',
   't'],
  ['u',
   'v',
   'w',
   'x',
   'y',
   'z']]]
```

How can I get test1 and test2 into a list, but as two separate items:

```
[ ['test1'], ['test2'] ]
```

It seems easy, but I am unsure of how to use list comprehension or traversing through a list to get this, because some of the values contain 8 entities, and some contain 6.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly are you trying to do. Perhaps put trash data instead of placeholders? It's not quite clear what criterion you use to extract the data you want.

Comment: I changed the data using letters and put what I need to get extracted. I've tried using list traversal - for val in list: print(val[4]) but that doesn't work

Comment: How do you identify your desired element?

Comment: I said it... test1 and test2. I don’t understand why this is getting downvoted

Comment: You aren't making it clear. Do you want a specific index, a particular regular expression match or something else?

Comment: @abarnet answered the question. I just wanted the specific index, but was unsure how to get it

Comment: You did not state that in your question. The fact that abarnert has a vast knowledge of the language and an uncanny ability to guess poorly stated intentions in no way removes the onus of asking a proper question from your shoulders.

Comment: Apologies for that

Comment: No worries. I hope that answers any doubts you may have about why your question was closed. There's always next time.

Comment: Is there a link/faq that I could read for proper question structure? Thanks again for clarifying!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try to put it in English terms first, then translate to Python.

- You have a top-level list. You want the `prof-name` from each of its sublists.
- Each sublist has two sub-sublists. You only want the first sub-sublist.
- Each sub-sublist has a bunch of strings, either 6 or 8. Either way, you only want the fourth one.

Each of those is pretty easy to translate into Python:

- Each sublist: `for sublst in lst`.
- The first element of each sublist: `sublst[0]`.
- The fourth element of each sub-sublist: `sublst[0][3]`.

Putting it together:

```
[sublst[0][3] for sublst in lst]
```

That English description works for your example, so the code works for your example. If it's not the right set of rules to apply, come up with a different set of rules that *do*, and they'll be just as easy to translate.

For example, maybe you don't want the fourth one, you want the ones that start with `prof-`?

In that case:

- Each sublist.
- First sub-sublist.
- Each element of the sub-sublist that starts with `Prof-`.

The last one is a bit tricky—we can't just do `element.startswith('Prof-')`, because some of the elements are integers. So let's write a function:

```
def prof(element):
    return isinstance(element, str) and element.startswith('Prof-')
```

Now:

- `for sublst in lst`
- `sublst[0]`
- `for element in sublst[0] if prof(element)`

Putting that together:

```
[element for sublst in lst for element in sublst[0] if prof(element)]
```

But maybe that's *too* dense. Once you've got three clauses in a comprehension, it gets hard to reason about it. Maybe we should first flatten it, then filter it:

```
elements = (element for sublst in lst for element in sublst[0])
profs = [element for element in elements if prof(element)]
```

A bit longer, but hopefully easier to understand.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know how to put it in those terms

Answer (score 1):

For this layout specifically:

```
oldlist = your_input_list
prof_dict={}
newlist=[]
for idx,entries in enumerate(oldlist[0]):
    newlist.append([entries[0][3]])
    prof_dict[idx]=entries[0][3]]
```

This produces the asked for list (contained in `newlist`) and a dictionary (`prof_dict`) to accompany so you can identify where in the list your professor name appeared in a very simple way, in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [[[21434,
   'CSCI 1111',
   'MPA 310',
   'Prof-name',
   'yes',
   'Introduction to Software Development',
   '3.00',
   'TR11:10AM - 12:25PM'],
  [2143521434,
   'CSCI 1111',
   'TOMP 405',
   'Laboratory',
   21434,
   'T04:10PM - 06:00PM']],
 [[21434,
   'CSCI 1111',
   'MPA 310',
   'Prof-name',
   'yes',
   'Introduction to Software Development',
   '3.00',
   'TR11:10AM - 12:25PM'],
  [2189021434,
   'CSCI 1111',
   'TOMP 406',
   'Laboratory',
   21434,
   'T04:10PM - 06:00PM']]]


prof_list = []
for xlist in x:
    for l in xlist:
        if len(l) == 8:
            prof_list.append(l[3])

print(prof_list)
```

OR

```
prof_list = [l[3] for xlist in x for l in xlist if len(l) == 8]
print(prof_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
def flatten(d):
  for i in d:
    if isinstance(i, str):
      if i.startswith('test'):
        yield [i]
    else:
      yield from flatten(i)

print(list(flatten(data)))
```

Output:

```
[['test1'], ['test2']]
```